# Smarty assign value to an array variable

Tags: arrays, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I am using SMARTY and I need to create an array and assign value to a particular index of it.

this is my php code:

```
   $tag = str_replace('-', ' ',$_GET['tag']);
    $tag = strip_tags(trim(mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($tag)))); // the tags word variable
    $smarty->assign('tag',$tag);


    $tag_sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_published='0' AND item_tags LIKE '%$tag%' ";
$tag_query = mysql_query($tag_sql);
    while ($tag_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tag_query)) {
   $items[] = $tag_row;
 }
    $smarty->assign('items',$items); // assign the  items loop to smarty
```

when i use this code in smarty template

```
 {section name=x loop=$items } {$items[x].item_url} {/section}
```

html output is

```
http://google.com http://yahoo.com
```

I want to be html output

```
'http://google.com','http://yahoo.com'
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Edit your question and show what's your data in PHP, now it's really hard to say what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
{section name=x loop=$items } {append var="urls" value="'`$items[x].item_url`'"} {/section}

{","|implode:$urls}
```

Output for that is:

```
'http://google.com','http://yahoo.com'
```

For Smarty 2 you can use:

```
{section name=x loop=$items } '{$items[x].item_url}'{if not $smarty.section.x.last},{/if} {/section}
```

Comment: The following errors occurred Fatal error: Smarty error: [in tag.html line 44]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'append' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590) in C:\wamp\www\include\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1095

Comment: @user3778067 you didn't paste any error. What version of Smarty do you use?

Comment: updated smarty to Releases version and problem is fixed thanks

Comment: @user3778067 I've edited my answer and added also solution for Smarty 2

Comment: can u help me for other problem?

Comment: @user3778067 If you have another problem, you should create new question and you should always mention your software version

Comment: please answer this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979515/how-to-put-b-tag-in-strang-in-smarty-template