# how to put <b> tag in string in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I am using SMARTY and I need to put `<b>` tag in string in the following php code i can put  tag in string

```
$search = 'this is my sample strangا';
$dbContent = 'this strang is for sample hello world';

$search = explode( ' ' , $search );
function wrapTag($inVal){
  return '<b>'.$inVal.'</b>';
}
$replace = array_map( 'wrapTag' , $search );

$dbContent = str_replace( $search , $replace , $dbContent );

echo $dbContent;
```

how to use this code in smarty template or how to convert this code for smarty

Comment: just put that php code inside a smarty plugin: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl

Comment: You should use `<strong>` instead of `<b>` as stated by http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp "Note: According to the HTML 5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the <h1> to <h6> tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the <em> tag, important text should be denoted with the <strong> tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the <mark> tag."

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I think `strang` is supposed to be `string`

Comment: @ctwheels I thought it maybe was supposed to be `strong`. Anyone has other clues? :)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I was staring at that for a few minutes and started saying it in different accents. The southerner accent worked for string

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no need put such code into Smarty template, so the only thing you should do is

```
$smarty->assign('dbContent', $dbContent);
```

and in Smarty template file:

```
{$dbContent}
```

You should separate logic and display. In this case you shouldn't rather move this code to Smarty. If Your wrapTag function contained a lot of HTML you could do it this way ( I know global is not nice solution but probably it could be done also in the other way):

```
function wrapTag($inVal){
  global $smarty;
  $smarty->assign('inVal', $inVal);
  return $smarty->fetch('bold_template.tpl');
}
```

and inside bold_template.tpl you could have:

```
<b>{$inVal}</b>
```

But if you only add `<b>` tags there's no point to put it in Smarty template